# What does NOOT mean?

Tags: slang, neologisms

I was listening to [Vertigo NCS release](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6CQHm0jvgkw), on YouTube and every comment underneath was like "IT'S HIGH NOOT NOOT."

> - 98%-ITS HIGH NOOT NOOT
>     2%- Random Comments
> - It's high NOOT NOOT!!!!!!!

I'm not from an English background, so I don't understand what it means. Does anyone know?

Comment: *I was **listening** to **V**ertigo's ncs release*. Vertigo is a band, right? Now I'm going to have Google them, and this ncs release too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the fuss derives from a mashed [first-person shooter](https://youtu.be/Ba-8xxvsOQQ?t=1m23s) compilation made by someone called 
Hoby who has 96,000 subscribers on YouTube

In the clip, someone off screen  repeats *high noon* several times (click on link). I believe *high noot noot* is a mock imitation of that expression, and has probably become a catchphrase among hardcore gamers.

UPDATED
Toward the end of the video compilation, the shooter turns around and reveals himself to be Pingu. This is the [link](https://youtu.be/Ba-8xxvsOQQ?t=2m47s) of that precise moment (02.47). Warning: keep the volume down on your speakers.

[image]

Disclaimer
I just limited myself to reading the semi-literate replies on YouTube page

Comment: Keep mixing links with one another, I can no longer multi-task. I'm getting far too old for this.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on context, is your case it probably means "*nonsense*":

“***[Noot Noot](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/noot-noot)”***:

> - is the sound made by the titular character from the British-Swiss children’s [TV series Pingu](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pingu). Due to its frequent utterance throughout the series, the soundbite of the catchphrase has been incorporated into a variety of pop music mash-ups and photoshopped images on Tumblr.

(knowyourmeme.com)

Comment: [YouTube compilation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a4VvRWTD3Ok)

Comment: Maybe a mash up of diffferent memes? http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/it-s-high-noon

Comment: 1+ Without your answer, my answer wouldn't have been possible. I am *not* a fan of first-person shooter games or compilations about them, but "high nonsense" didn't make much sense to me.